# Adding a default gateway to linux does not take affect and it just uses the

Tags: routing, redhat, linux-networking

I have a server and a firewall in a cloud environment, the details are as follows,
[image]

with the following details for each component,

| Name | IP | MAC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| server | 192.168.232.6 | c6:b0:c0:a8:e8:06 |
| firewall | 192.168.232.3 | c6:b0:c0:a8:e8:03 |
| default gateway | 192.168.232.1 | 00:03:ba:da:0c:b7 |

As this is based in the cloud, I do not have any control of the default gateway and cannot make any changes to it. I would like to route external traffic through the firewall by setting the default gateway on the server as the firewall's IP. I did this by running the following command,

```
ip route add default via 192.168.232.3
```

I have confirmed this has worked by running the following commands,

```
route
ip route get 8.8.8.8
```

The results are as follows,

[image]

However, when I initiate traffic from 192.168.232.6 to an external host, I do not see the traffic hitting the firewall. There is no firewall/network rules in between the firewall and the server.

I have checked my arp table and it is as you would expect,
[image]

When I run the following command and run a packet capture,

```
telnet 8.8.8.8 8089
```

I get the following results,

[image]

The packets are leaving the server and heading towards the firewalls MAC, but I do not see the packets arrive (I have run a packet capture on the firewall and nothing)

Why Would this be? What can I investigate further from the host ?

Comment: Are you sure the firewall does not block your traffic? Can you ping the firewall?

Comment: I can ping the firewall and it returns a response. I have run a packet capture on the firewall and there is no traffic on the interface - it isn't even hitting the firewall